# captive portal - allow internet access after facebook like

Tags: facebook, portal, dd-wrt

I want to create a captive portal ( if possible in dd-wrt ) that has an open wifi network. When someone connects he gets a pop-up page that asks him to like a facebook page. If he likes ( or even better checks-in ) then the captive portal would allow full internet access. Any suggestions -  ideas?

Comment: Use [HotSpotSystem](http://HotSpotSystem.com)

Comment: This is a nice service but it is a very expensive one. I'm looking for something open-source

Comment: were you able to find a way to implement this? If yes, please share.